# Preservation of context-free languages under prefix and suffix elimination

Tags: context-free

Let $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ be our alphabet. Let $L$ be some context-free language, which is known to start and end with 0's, meaning that every word $x$ in $L$ has a form $x=0y0$. Let $M$ be a language obtained from $L$ by deleting one starting and one ending $0$, $L=0 \cdot M \cdot 0$.

My question:

Is $M$ still context-free? It seems yes, however I can't prove it. I have tried to construct a push down automaton for $M$ from that of $L$. However, starting $0$ seems to give possibly infinite amount of configurations. So I don't know what to do.

If this question appeared somewhere, I would be grateful if you could provide a reference or a link. 
Thanks.

Comment: The question was edited. Previously it was not stated explicitly that we delete exactly one $0$ at the beginning and exactly one $0$ at the end. Sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: I have added the actual case to my answer. Here the starting $0$ does not give infinitely many possible configurations. The transition reading the initial $0$ can only put one element on the stack. You just need to get this element there without actually reading the $0$.

Answer (score 1):

I answer for the case that an arbitrary number of leading or trailing $0$ can be deleted. This supposes that your $L=0M0$ is wrong; it would mean that all words in $L$ start and end with $0$. Since the rest of your question does ot seem to imply this and since that case would be rather trivial, I ignore this equation and answer what I understand from the rest of the question.

You are right. There is no bound on the number of 0 in the beginning, and each one of them can put something on the stack. Thus there is an infinite number of possible stack configurations that can be reached after reading them.

My idea is this: essentially we replace the transitions that read $0$ by ones that read the empty string $\lambda$. The problems are now that $0$ inside $M$ must still be read and that the $\lambda$-transitions could be executed inside $M$, too.

Therefore we make three copies of the sets of states and transitions. In the first one we replace input $0$s  by $\lambda$ in all transitions. All transitions reading an input different from $0$ lead to the corresponding state in the second copy of the state set.

The second set works like the original PDA reading the word from $M$. For every transition that reads $0$ we add a copy that leads to the corresponding state in the third set; these amount to guesses that the current $0$ starts a final block of only $0$.

The third set works much like the first (reading $\lambda$ instead of $0$), only for inputs other than $0$ it rejects.

For the $L=0M0$ case you can adapt this contruction as follows: all the new $\lambda$-transitions from the first set lead immediately to states of the second set. In this way only one leading $0$ is simulated. For the termination: go to a special final state after simulating the read of one $0$.